# keep table(rows) together with OpenXML SDK 2.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I'd like to generate multiple tables with 2 rows each inside of a word document. But I want to keep these two rows together (if possible).

1. `new KeepNext()`on the first row doesn't work
2. `new KeepNext()`on the last paragraph of the first row doesn't work
3. `new CantSplit()` on the table doesn't work

In all cases the second row (if too large) lands on the second page. A `new CantSplit()` on the last cell ( the one with large content) avoids a break of the cell. But none of the options avoids a split of the table (rowwise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a KeepNext to *each* row to keep them together. The XML output in document.xml should be something akin to:

[image]

This code successfully creates a table with 2 rows that will stay together across pages:

```
Table table = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Table());

TableRow row1 = table.AppendChild(new TableRow());
TableCell cell1 = row1.AppendChild(new TableCell());
Paragraph para1 = cell1.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
PreviousParagraphProperties prop1 = para1.AppendChild(new PreviousParagraphProperties());
KeepNext k = prop1.AppendChild(new KeepNext());
Run run1 = para1.AppendChild(new Run());
run1.AppendChild(new Text("This is some long text"));

TableRow row2 = table.AppendChild(new TableRow());
TableCell cell2 = row2.AppendChild(new TableCell());
Paragraph para2 = cell2.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
PreviousParagraphProperties prop2 = para1.AppendChild(new PreviousParagraphProperties());
KeepNext k2 = prop2.AppendChild(new KeepNext());
Run run2 = para2.AppendChild(new Run());
run2.AppendChild(new Text("This is some even longer text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i did it like this when I had to apply this to all tables:

private static void AlterTableType(List<Table> t)
    {
        foreach (Table table in t)
        {
            foreach (TableRow row in table.Descendants<TableRow>())
            {
                TableRowProperties trP = new TableRowProperties();
                CantSplit split = new CantSplit();
                trP.Append(split);
                row.AppendChild(trP);
            }
        }
    }
```

getting all tables

```
var t = package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Table>().ToList()
```