# C# generate MS Word with Open XML table in document crash

Tags: c#, openxml

I use C# and Open XML to generate MS Word document, here this word file that I generated.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9vSVV3dDAmFU0dOSThjSk14WXM/view

On page 2 the table hover to another one. (You will see the same on page 5 too)

I can fix it (some case) by manual set whole table to show in one page, to do this i just add enter before or after table. This method not work all time and my user, they will not like it for sure.

I thing it may be my paragraph or table properties setting but i can't find the way to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep table(rows) together with OpenXML SDK 2.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995999/keep-tablerows-together-with-openxml-sdk-2-5)

Comment: In my code i don't use KeepNext but for sure i recheck my DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body element on debug mode and they don't have KeepNext element too.

Comment: Well if they did your problem would've been solved wouldn't it? `KeepNext` is used to keep them together like you want